# Postgres vs oracle doing 1 million sqrts am I doing it wrong?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, postgresql, amazon-web-services

We am trying to get an idea of the raw performance of Oracle vs PostgreSQL. We have extensive oracle experience but are new to PostgreSQL. We are going to run lots of queries with our data, etc. But first we wanted to see just how they perform on basic kernel tasks, i.e. math and branching since SQL is built on that.

In AWS RDS we created two db.m3.2xlarge instances one with oracle 11.2.0.4.v1 license included, the other with PostgreSQL (9.3.3)

In both we ran code that did 1 million square roots (from 1 to 1 mill).  Then did the same but within an If..Then statement.

The results were a bit troubling:

```
Oracle      4.8 seconds

PostgreSQL  21.803 seconds
```

adding an if statement:

```
Oracle      4.78 seconds

PostgreSQL  24.4 seconds
```

code 
Oracle square root

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET TIMING ON

DECLARE
  n NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR f IN 1..10000000
LOOP
    n := SQRT (f);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

PostgreSQL

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$ DECLARE n real;
BEGIN
FOR f IN 1..10000000 LOOP
n = SQRT (f);
END LOOP;
RAISE NOTICE 'Result => %',n;
END $$;
```

oracle adding if

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET TIMING ON

DECLARE
  n NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR f IN 1..10000000
LOOP
  if 0 =0 then
    n := SQRT (f);
    end if;
  END LOOP;
```

postgres adding if

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$ DECLARE n real;
BEGIN
FOR f IN 1..10000000 LOOP
if 0=0 then 
n = SQRT (f);
end if;
END LOOP;
RAISE NOTICE 'Result => %',n;
END $$;
```

I used an anonymous block for PostgreSQL.  I also did it as a function and got identical results

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testpostgrescpu()
  RETURNS real AS
$BODY$
declare
     n real;
BEGIN
   FOR f IN 1..10000000 LOOP        
    n = SQRT (f);       
   END LOOP;        


   RETURN n;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION testpostgrescpu()
  OWNER TO xxx
```

Based on what we had heard of PostgreSQL and how it is comparable to Oracle in many ways, we were taken aback by the results.  Did we code PostgreSQL incorrectly?  What are we missing or is this the way it is.

Note: once we started running queries on the exact same data in Oracle and PostgreSQL we saw a similar pattern.  On basic queries little difference, but as they started to get more and more complex Oracle was around 3-5 faster.

Again, this was run on identical AWS RDS instances, we ran them many times during the day on different days and results were always the same

Comment: Is it possible that the Oracle instance is multi-threaded?  I am really wondering if the default system parameters might be more efficient for the Oracle instance (this probably wouldn't affect the loop but it would affect other operations).

Comment: it not multi-threaded its multi-process as is PostgreSQL  Oracle can run multi-threaded but is seldom used as such

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, your example test is pretty meaningless.

I think the basic problem you are having is that you don't really know anything about PostgreSQL and are trying the same basic tricks you would with Oracle.

> We am trying to get an idea of the raw performance of Oracle vs PostgreSQL

Well that doesn't really *mean* anything does it? Unless you're trying to measure raw disk reads or some such.

> we have tuned them as much as possible (checked all parameters changed random page cost, set seq scan to off etc)

Well, setting seq_scan to off is unlikely to be something you'd want to do other than to force the planner while exploring a test case. What made you do that? Where in the manuals did it suggest it? You don't say *how* you changed random-page-cost nor how you determined you had the correct value.

> We discovered that with PostgreSQL if the table is >25% of the shared mem setting its table data is not cached.

Well, that's just clearly not possible. Caching takes place at the PostgreSQL and OS level and disk blocks *will* be cached. How are you measuring this?

> (in our case AWS 30 gig instance has a shared mem of 7 gigs, once we get the table size under 2gigs it starts getting cached again)

Well how are you sizing shared_mem then? I'm trying to imagine a scenario where 2G and 7G are both reasonable values and I'm having trouble. You don't supply any memory usage information, so no-one can tell what's going on though.

I think what you need to do is the following:

1. Get a good hot cup of tea /coffee.
2. Read through the [manuals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html).
3. Have a look through the wiki e.g. [Tuning Your PostgreSQL Server](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server).
4. Once you have a reasonable grip on how work-mem and shared-mem operate put some measurement in place on the server so you can see memory usage, disk I/O etc.
5. Make sure you have a [basic understanding](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_EXPLAIN) of how to [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) your queries.
6. Subscribe to one of the postgresql.org mailing-lists (performance seems plausible) so you have somewhere you can hold discussions.
7. *Then* start looking at measuring performance.

There *are* cases where Oracle will be smarter than PostgreSQL, but a general across-the-board major slow-down isn't what you'd expect to see.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of speculation.  I would expect Oracle to be slower than Postgres on such calculations.  However, I think your may have a performance problem that is in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html):

> The type numeric can store numbers with a very large number of digits
>   and perform calculations exactly. It is especially recommended for
>   storing monetary amounts and other quantities where exactness is
>   required. However, arithmetic on numeric values is very slow compared
>   to the integer types, or to the floating-point types described in the
>   next section.

Your code doesn't declare a data type for `f`.  By context, it would be assigned to be an integer.  However, the `sqrt()` function takes either floating point or a `numeric` constant.  These are not equivalent (and I'm guessing that when a `numeric`, the function is slower).  My guess is that the integer `f` is converted to a `number` rather than a `real` for the operation.

Try running the test by explicitly declaring `f` to be `real` or by casting it before the function call.  That might improve performance.

Comment: made f real exact same time.  also made f an integer and exact same time       DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$ 
DECLARE n real;
DECLARE f real;
BEGIN
FOR f IN 1..10000000 LOOP
n = SQRT (f);
END LOOP;
RAISE NOTICE 'Result => %',n;
END $$;

Comment: Gordon see my comment to Hambone below.  1 million index loopups oracle 3-4 times faster

Answer (score 2):

I can't see how this will be a useful metric unless you happen to do a lot of computation in pl/sql or pg pl/sql. This isn't really recommended anyway and can be done natively in C or by calling Java classes. Oracle can compile pl/sql natively to c on some platforms / versions and so this may be one of the reasons why you see a big difference in speed.

The speed of a database would be better determined by its ability to perform queries probably including joins with the correct statistics in place or to write and update data. For databases such as Oracle and Postgres sql doing this in a multi-user and transactional environment would be an even better test assuming you have an OLTP application. From what I hear Postgres is doing pretty well with competing with Oracle but it depends on your application.

For better description and analysis of Oracle I'd suggest looking at the asktom https://asktom.oracle.com/ forums. I'm not sure if there is anything close to this for postgres.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, your benchmark is completely meaningless.

You're computing 1 million square roots and *immediately throw away the results*; depending on your optimization settings, I'd expect the compiler to completely get rid of your loop.

You should *at least* store the results somewhere or use them for another computation (e.g. by computing the sum).

Also, I have to disagree with your statement *i.e. math and branching since SQL is built on that*. A RDBMS does a lot of things, but computing square roots efficiently is certainly not one of its strong sides. If you really, really need this kind of computation, it would make much more sense to move this out of the database and use some kind of specialized software for that, e.g. **R** .

Comment: You're right the whole look was most probably excluded by the Oracle optimizer. Oracle's PL/SQL (ADA like) is optimized on two levels p-code, m-code and various optimizations take place. For example in some cases Oracle uses bulk operations even if you do not use them in your source.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little surprised by these benchmarks, but I'm inclined to notionally agree with Frank Schmitt.  While I wouldn't go so far as to say it's "completely meaningless," if you are going to compare two DBMS systems, I would think you would want to look at much more than just how each one does math.

For what it's worth, I used Oracle almost exclusively at my former employer.  In my new role, our primary DBMS is Sybase ASE, which is lacking many of the tools I've been accustomed to using, and we are using PostgreSQL as a stop-gap.

There are undoubtedly better write-ups than what I am about to provide, but from a novice's point of view:

Things I miss about Oracle:

- OS-authentication (ability to let users log in based on their Windows/Unix Credentials), with no messy password issues
- the "merge" statement
- bulk inserts and updates through OCI (ODP.net, DBD::Oracle)
- the ability to commit partially through a procedure
- availability of awesome IDEs (like All Around Automation PL/SQL Developer)
- bitmap indexes
- more seamless DBlinks

Things I like about PostgreSQL:

- the price tag
- "copy" is so much easier to use than SQL*Loader
- the availablity of drivers like ODBC and Npgsql.dll for .NET that somehow just work
- custom functions inside of SQL don't drag down query performance
- ability to create custom functions in languages other than PL (ie Perl)
- easier to use data types, like a date, time, timestamp and interval
- an update syntax that is borderline intuitive (and doesn't require the additional exists wrapper)

Again, I'm far from an expert.  Both database platforms are a joy to work with and take care of so much of the heavy lifting.

-- edit --

And I should add, to this day I never figured out how to do this in Oracle:

```
select * from pg_views
where definition like '%inventory.turns%'
```

Comment: Guys you are missing the point.  We don't care what we are doing a 1 million times it see how algorithms are implemented, how efficient is the code etc.

So now we did the following.  We have a table that has 5000000 rows.  We created a loop from 1 to a million that selected the same row from the table via the primary key (select key_id  into n from tablea where primary_id = 11684473;).  We did a unique index scan on the same row 1 million times.  so we had 1 physical read and then 999999 from cache.

oracle 27 seconds
postgreSQL 96 seconds

again the 3-4 times metric comes up.

Comment: also with regard to  "copy" is so much easier to use than SQL*Loader  keep in mind that a single error and the whole load dies either everything loads or nothing loads.  sqloader allows bad files max number of errors etc     custom functions inside of SQL don't drag down query performance  oracle allows you to index functions               ability to create custom functions in languages other than PL  oracle can do it in C++ or JAVA    oracle has timestamp and interval data types

Comment: It's hard to believe Oracle is that much "better," but the examples you've displayed thus far are both head scratchers.  I'm curious how the performance delta on AWS differs from a native server.  What Operating system are your OWS instances?

Comment: Also, and I know I'm drifting off-topic, but regarding copy, I would argue the opposite can be true.  On a truncate/copy, if anything fails, then the table reverts to its original state.  I think there are many cases where an old, good snapshot would be preferrable to a partial (or incomplete) one.  With Oracle, when you truncate, it's a done deal.  I'm not necessarily buying or selling, but I think copy is easier to use and has its merits outside of ease as well.

Comment: Hambone, we are in the processing of doing a full test using queries that we have in our production environment and results are even more distressing for PostgreSQL.  our queries are complex (25 table joins with a dozen filters) and we have loaded around 500 gigs of data.  the best PostgreSQL does is 1/2 the speed of oracle, most are 4-5x slower and some are 50-100x slower.  we have tuned them as much as possible (checked all parameters changed random page cost, set seq scan to off etc) but still most run  mcuh slower.

Comment: Another concern is that when we tested against development data we noticed that the queries were cached so that subsequent runs were much faster  However against prod data where most of our tables are very big, subsequent runs were at the same speed.  We discovered that with PostgreSQL if the table is >25% of the shared mem setting its table data is not cached.  (in our case AWS 30 gig instance has a shared mem of 7 gigs, once we get the table size under 2gigs it starts getting cached again)

Comment: @user3689158 Please don't add additional information in comments - edit your question instead (using the "Edit" button :-) ). Also, IMHO, this question is better suited for dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is with type casting. PostgreSQL `sqrt` function is defined as accepting double precision (float) or numeric.
So what happens in your code is that the integer is casted to float (which is fast) the float version of `sqrt` and the result is the type casted from float to real (which is slow).

To see what I am talking about, try to just compare runtime of these two code samples:

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
DECLARE n real;
BEGIN
    FOR f IN 1..10000000 LOOP
        n = f::float;
    END LOOP;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Result => %',n;
END $$;

DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
DECLARE n float;
BEGIN
    FOR f IN 1..10000000 LOOP
        n = f::float;
    END LOOP;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Result => %',n;
END $$;
```

On my machine first one takes 16s and the second one only 3s.

The moral of the story is that you need to be careful about data types you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You are not performing any PostgreSQL benchmark.

What you are really doing is a pl/pgsqlbenchmark.

You could use any of these [PostgreSQL language extensions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/external-pl.html) for this test, and you would probably get rather different results.

There is a pl/pgsql interpreter that will execute your code. It is installed along with PostgreSQL by default.
For further information:

- [pl/pgsql
  implementation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html)
- [pl/pgsql
  overview](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-overview.html)

Using pl/java you would have a JVM running, pl/sh a shell running.

Comment: Adding explanation with url would make it much easier

Answer (score 0):

`plpgsql` is not an extensively optimized-for-performance language.

I don't know why I would ever want to compute 10 million square roots in an explicit loop inside the database, but if I did I would use `plperl` to do it.